# string splitting in python with ignoring \r \n cases

Tags: python, split, filenames, command-line-arguments

I am having this problem which is really weird I am trying to solve it and i can't find the best way.

I am passing this string as an argv[] "copy c:\root c:\noot" in python.

and i want to gave c:\root and c:\noot all together as one piece when splitting

example:

```
commandLineOptions = "copy c:\root c:\noot" # this is passed from cmd. 
x = commandLineOptions.split() 
print x 
[copy , c:\root , c:\noot]
```

cheers,

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to pass it in one piece, all together, then why are you using split()?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Can you please elaborate what actually you want, preferably with eg of what you want ?

Comment: Take care with your commands; writing `copy c:\root` in command-line is not equivalent to Python `c = "copy c:\root"`, as `\r` or `\n` are special characters in Python scripts (there are others). You should either write `c = r"copy c:\root"` or `c = "copy c:\\root"`.

Answer (score 3):

`str.split` accepts second parameter - maximum number of 'splits':

```
>>> commandLineOptions = "copy c:\root c:\noot"
>>> commandLineOptions.split(' ', 1)
['copy', 'c:\root c:\noot']
```